# Using Underscore.js's invoke with lastIndexOf

Tags: javascript, invoke, underscore.js

```
// Why doesn't this:
_.invoke(['D','C'], 'lastIndexOf', ['A','B','C'])

// Return this:
[-1,2]?
```

I've got a string. (Input)

**'ABC'**

Split into an array. (InputBuffer)

**['A','B','C']**

I've also got an array with arbitrary characters. (TriggerChars)

**['D','E']**

<del>I want to check the last item in the InputBuffer to see if matched any of the TriggerChars.</del>

I want to get the last occurrence of both TriggerChars in the InputBuffer.

```
_.invoke(['D','E'], 'lastIndexOf', ['A','B','C']);
// Returns [-1,-1] since C isn't D or E.


_.invoke(['D','C'], 'lastIndexOf', ['A','B','C']);
// Why doesn't this return [-1,2]

_.lastIndexOf(['A','B','C'],'D') == -1
_.lastIndexOf(['A','B','C'],'C') == 2
```

What am I not getting with Invoke?
http://underscorejs.org/#invoke

Comment: Looks to me as if underscore does not iterate over the array but is treating it it as a "single" argument? Your `_.invoke(['D','E'], 'lastIndexOf', ['A','B','C']);` might as well be false false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
_.map(['D', 'C'], function (x) { return _.lastIndexOf(['A', 'B', 'C'], x)})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var InputBuffer = ["A","B","C"];
var TriggerChars = ["D","E"];

_.indexOf( TriggerChars, InputBuffer[InputBuffer.length-1] ) > -1;
```

Evaluates to `true` if this: *I want to check the last item in the InputBuffer to see if matched any of the TriggerChars.*

Comment: Oups! I was meaning to write one thing and wrote something very different. Sorry! I want to get the last occurrence of both TriggerChars in the InputBuffer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var inputBuffer = ["A","B","C"];  
var triggerChars = ["D","E"];

triggerChars.indexOf(inputBuffer[inputBuffer.length-1]) > -1
```

or just skip underscore, the exact same solution above except the dependency,

ok I updated it alittle

```
var inputBuffer = ["A","B","C"];  
var triggerChars = ["D","C"];  

var index = [];

for(var i = 0; i < triggerChars.length; i++){
   index.push(inputBuffer.lastIndexOf(triggerChars[i]));
}

console.log(index);

-> [-1,2]
```

Comment: I'm so sorry. I was meaning to write one thing and wrote something else. I want to get the last occurrence of both TriggerChars in the InputBuffer.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with the underscore version of it since I already have it in the project.